# php check open through iframe

Tags: php

I want to check using php if the current page is called by an iframe and not directly in the browser.

It's a page that gets some $_POST parameters while the sending form's target is an iframe, so the page will display in an iframe.

I want to check that using PHP, How?

Thanks.

Comment: Totally impossible to check for sure if it's an iframe.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. PHP runs serverside.  It is for all intents and purposes the same thing as the webserver -- it sees HTTP requests and returns responses.  An iframe is a clientside mechanism implemented by the browser that simply allows you to display 2 or more html pages (the response payload).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SERVER HTTP_REFERER

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Comment: recommendation: if you submit the iframe window you should save the referrer in the form as a hidden field. This will pass the original referrer (the one who called the iframe at first).